# ERROR: extra data after last expected column : PGADMIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I'm trying to import a CSV ([Cities.csv](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/csv/csv.html)) onto my Postgres using pg-admin. I understand this is a common problem, found few answers on SO. But, how do we address this through pg-admin?.

[image]

[image: Error]

Comment: Can you also share the create table of `ei_test`?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on a tool like pgAdmin to import data. It indeed provides a nice user interface and is quite intuitive, but `psql` is imho still by far the most flexible choice.

Note: Your CSV file has an empty line in the end, which is probably causing the error. One option to filter it out is to use `sed` (see example below). In that way the `COPY` command already gets the records clean and ready to be imported.

```
$ sed -e /^$/d cities.csv | psql -d mydb -c "COPY ei_test FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER;"
```

And your data is ready to use ..

```
SELECT * FROM ei_test LIMIT 10;

 latd | latm | lats | ns | lond | lonm | lons | ew |       city       | state 
------+------+------+----+------+------+------+----+------------------+-------
   41 |    5 |   59 |  N |   80 |   39 |    0 |  W |  Youngstown      |  OH
   42 |   52 |   48 |  N |   97 |   23 |   23 |  W |  Yankton         |  SD
   46 |   35 |   59 |  N |  120 |   30 |   36 |  W |  Yakima          |  WA
   42 |   16 |   12 |  N |   71 |   48 |    0 |  W |  Worcester       |  MA
   43 |   37 |   48 |  N |   89 |   46 |   11 |  W |  Wisconsin Dells |  WI
   36 |    5 |   59 |  N |   80 |   15 |    0 |  W |  Winston-Salem   |  NC
   49 |   52 |   48 |  N |   97 |    9 |    0 |  W |  Winnipeg        |  MB
   39 |   11 |   23 |  N |   78 |    9 |   36 |  W |  Winchester      |  VA
   34 |   14 |   24 |  N |   77 |   55 |   11 |  W |  Wilmington      |  NC
   39 |   45 |    0 |  N |   75 |   33 |    0 |  W |  Wilmington      |  DE
(10 Zeilen)
```